# React-Native TextInput showSoftInputOnFocus not work well

Tags: android, react-native

There are two `TextInput`s in my code. One of them I set its `showSoftInputOnFocus` to `true`, I want to show keyboard when it focused. The other one I set its `showSoftInputOnFocus` to `false`, I don't want to show keyboard when it focused.

```
<View>
  <Text style={_label}>Field1</Text>
  <TextInput
    value={value1}
    showSoftInputOnFocus={false}
    keyboardType="numeric"
  />
</View>
<View>
  <Text style={_label}>Field2</Text>
  <TextInput
    value={value2}
    autoFocus={true}
    showSoftInputOnFocus={true}
  />
</View>
```

When the second `TextInput` focused, the keyboard displayed. Then I press the first `TextInput`, it focused, but the keyboard remained on the screen, it doesn't dismiss.

I try to add `onBlur={Keyboard.dismiss}` to the second `TextInput`. When I switch the cursor from the second `TextInput` to the first, the keyboard is indeed hidden, but the first `TextInput` is not focused. I must press the first `TextInput` again to make it focused.

How to make the first `TextInput` get focus immediately when I press it?

Answer (score 1):

There's a prop called `keyboardShouldPersistTaps` for `ScrollView`s, it changes the behavior of touches when the keyboard is shown. Try to add a `ScrollView` in your main view:

```
<View>
    <ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always'>
        ...
    </ScrollView>
</View>
```

Comment: it not works. The second `TextInput` is focused now, I want to hide keyboard and make the first `TextInput` focused immediately when I press it. But now I must press twice to make the first `TextInput` focused.

Comment: Hey @afishhhhh, did you solve it? I am getting the same problem.

Comment: oh hey! first sorry @afishhhhh just noticed your comment after 3 years lol. Anw what you can do is just make your first `TextInput` focus in the `onBlur` function you added to the second. Ofc you can make it focus by taking a reference of it and calling .focus() on it

Comment: Hey @afishhhhh, i dont think this is a good idea. What if i am in second input then i clicked somewhere outside of the input ( not on the first input ), this will also focus the first input which is not so reasonable.

Comment: You play with your logic, you got the idea, you can just use conditions as you like to apply your logic